# Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse) scroll lock, disable autoscroll

Tags: eclipse, logging, spring-tool-suite

My application is all the time creating some logs.

Sometimes, when some exception occurs, I would like to disable scroll to check the stack trace. I do have "Scroll Lock" button pressed. When I go up with the scroll I am able to stop where I want, but if only I use my scroll to go down a little bit, the Scroll Lock button automatically gets unpressed.

Is there a way to stop Eclipse from auto-scrolling my logs?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link it has some useful information about it.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=149393